# xpath match not working

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to fetch the content of message field with  `"//td[text()='message']/following-sibling::*/text()"` from this result ( from curl ):

```
<BODY bgcolor=#dddddd>
<TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>Something</B></TD>
<TD>ca</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>Some list</B></TD>
<TD>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>CA</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>message</B></TD>
<TD>CA already existed.</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
<br>
```

But it doenst seens to work, The funny thing is using the same expression with python i can get it to work. So, how could i get the content of the message field?

PS: I'm using this online tester tool: http://www.xpathtester.com/test

EDIT: This is my actual php code:

```
<?php

function get_url_data($acl)
{
     // curl request
     $xml_content = http_request($acl);
     echo $xml_content ;
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadXML($xml_content);
     $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
     $content_title = $xpath->query("//td[text()='message']/following-sibling::*/text()");
     return $content_title;
}
if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false){ 

//Convert content of text area into an array
$data = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['sendme']));
}
foreach  ($data as $name => $value){
    $content = get_url_data($value);
    foreach ($content as $value)
    {
        echo $value->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Add the markup you're working with.

Comment: Are you working with DomDocument or SimpleXMLElement ? Which XSLT Parser are you using?

Comment: @ToBe Thanks for the observation, info added.

Comment: Is xpath case sensitive with it's node names?

Comment: Your xpath seems a bit risky, what happens if someone changed your html or added new texts? Can you add id attributes to your html nodes? Those would dramatically improve your xpath parsing.

Comment: I would check first if the expression `"//td[text()='message']"` actually retrieves a `<td>` element, because it seems *possible* to me, that `text()='message'` expression might evaluate *true* on a `<b>` subelement, which has no following sibling and is not `<td>` at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false){ 

//Convert content of text area into an array
$data = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST['sendme']));
}
foreach  ($data as $name => $value){
    $content = create_acl($value);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    @$doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $filtered = $xpath->query("//td[text()='message']/following-sibling::*/text()");
    foreach ($filtered as $e) {
      echo $e->nodeValue;
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```